# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] when saving data into new array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

i have angular controller, which looks like this:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, serverData) {
    $scope.playersData = function() {
        var players = [],
            listed = [], name;

        serverData.forEach(function(result) {
            name = result.name;
            if(listed.indexOf(name) === -1) {
                 players.push({
                       name: name,
                       scoreSum: 20
                    });
                listed.push(name);
            }
        });

        return players;
    };
});
```

serverData are created in app like this: `app.value('serverData', [...])`

And if i use it in template like this: `<li ng-repeat="player in playersData() | orderBy:'name'">{{player.name}}</li>`

I get Error: [$rootScope:infdig]
I read http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope:infdig, but i do not understand, where is my binding wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes you get a better, more descriptive error, if you include the non-minified version of AngularJS instead of `angular.min.js`.

Comment: could you provide and example in fiddle or plunkr? What is ServerData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/csFmMiymkXC3q5CLB2tM?p=preview)

Its a working example of your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error because your playersData function changes your model. When a digest happens, your `playesrData()` function runs, which then inserts values into your players object... when angular sees the model has changed, it runs a digest.

When the digest runs, `playersData` will execute and the model will change... when the model changes the digest runs. When the digest runs, `playersData` will execute and the model will change... when the model changes the digest runs. When the digest runs, `playersData` will execute and the model will change... when the model changes the digest runs.

And then it gives up...

Also, it looks like your controller is returning a var that's local to your playeresData function... which is odd, I don't know what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I am trying to do 'Ember like computed property'. So basically filter and do some enhancements with `serverData` and return it to view. `players` is local property, maybe that is problem?

Comment: When you put a function on scope, it becomes automatically bindable. You can not change the model inside of that function because it will cause digest overflow. You must change the model before it gets to your scope, typically in a service. If you want to filter, use a filter function. Angular has some nice built-in filters. The big exception to this is if your model stabalizes! If your model keeps changing every iteration, you'll go over the limit. If your model stablizes and stops changing, it won't. Consider a function that returns a random #, the model never stabilizes.